# Hosting a Next JS website with big public folder

Tags: next.js, hosting

I plan on hosting a Next JS app which will contain a big public folder containing audio files and pictures. I'm fine with rebuilding it whenever I make a change to the files (for example uploading a new file via API route that saves the file in public folder) but what about code changes? What if at some point in the future I'd want to make changes to the source code? Would I have to upload the whole 10GB project folder again on the server and then run build command? Or is there a way to upload the code alone?

The point is that I'd like to host the ready project that already contains all media files (around 10GB of data) - which obviously can't be commited to Github as whole - and I'm concerned about probable future updates to the source code of the app. Do hosting providers in general have such ability?